# Vim macro to Camel_Case_With_Underscores

Tags: vim, vim-macros

I want a quick macro to allow me to convert text like qty_on_hand to Qty_On_Hand. Words that have no underscores should be capitalised so description would become Description. Case in the source text is not going to be consistent, so it might be QTY_on_Hand -> Qty_On_Hand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
:let @t="caw\<C-r>=join(map(split(@\", '_', 1), 'toupper(v:val[:0]).tolower(v:val[1:])'), '_')\n\e"
```

Then when you type `@t` in normal mode you will get current word replaced as you requested. If you want to just blindly replace everything, then use

```
:%s/\<\w\+\>/\=join(map(split(submatch(0), "_", 1), "toupper(v:val[:0]).tolower(v:val[1:])"), "_")/g
```

Add `c` after `g` flag if you want vim to ask you about each replacement.

Second solution assumes that there are no non-ASCII identifiers in your source code.

Comment: Strange, when I ran the macro it just replaced the word with the text of the macro. Is there some quoting issue maybe?

Comment: @Greg Reynolds. I forgot to mention that `<C-r>`, `<CR>` and `<Esc>` should be entered as `<C-v><C-r>`, `<C-v><CR>` and `<C-v><Esc>`. Alternatively, use double quotes outside and single inside: `:let @t="caw\<C-r>=join(map(split(@\", '_', 1), 'toupper(v:val[:0]).tolower(v:val[1:])'), '_')\n\e"`.